# Adding components to drop down

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a Matlab application. Every time a button is clicked, it needs to add the text in a particular text field into its own field in a drop-down window.

Error: 'Items' must be a cell array of character vectors.

```
//app.newFileTitleField.Value is what is inputted by user in text field

app.newFileTitleField.Value = 'hello';
app.OptionHolder = {};
app.OptionHolder {end+1} = [app.newFileTitleField.Value];
app.DropDown.Items = {app.OptionHolder};
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I get the error Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object. How do I fix this?

Comment: Not very easy to answer without a [mcve] and/or the entire error message.

Comment: is that any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `app.OptionHolder` appears to already be a cell array of character vectors, so this should work:

```
app.DropDown.Items = app.OptionHolder;
```

Also, the square brackets around `app.newFileTitleField.Value` are unnecessary.